# Navigator.pop() callback?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a callback function or a way to know that `Navigator.of(context).pop()`'s animation back into the previous screen has finished? currently Im using `await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));` to accomplish this. Is there a better way?

Im using it for `showModalBottomSheet(useRootNavigator: true)` then `Navigator.pop()` to close the bottom sheet, then push a new route.

code:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pop();
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
Navigator.of(context).push(...) // push new screen
```

Answer (score 11):

Pushing a route already maintains a Future that completes when a pop occurs. This means you can do this:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/someRoute').then((completion){
    //do something
});
```

The parameter named completion could also be any data you want to retrieve from the screen you are showing. For example let's say I have a group chat and I want to add a user to it. To do that I want to show a screen that allows me to pick a user then pass that user back to the previous screen.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/InviteToChatScreen').then((object) {
    if (object != null) {
        var user = object as User;
        //add them to the chat
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try with RouteAware, its provide few overrides Methods

```
didPop() → void
Called when the current route has been popped off.
didPopNext() → void
Called when the top route has been popped off, and the current route shows up.
didPush() → void
Called when the current route has been pushed.
didPushNext() → void
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteAware-class.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, "/route");
```